# Find the value of $m$ and $n$ Calculus related

Tags: calculus

Good day everyone. I really need help in this question, it kept me thinking for a few tens of minutes.

The gradient of the curve $y=mx^2+\frac{n}{x}$ at point $(2,12)$ is 6. Find the value of $m$ and $n$.

Here is my working;

$f'(x)=2mx-\frac{n}{x^2}$

Gradient is 6, so...

$6=4m-\frac{n}{4}$

From this, I got this equation, $n=16m-24$

That's where I can't continue anymore it confuses me! Please help me!

Comment: You can substitute the now known value of n back into the original equation, and as you know the point, you can substitute it back into the original f(x) with only one unknown value, m, to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $(2,12)$ is on the curve.  Substituting in the first equation  we get  $12=4m+\frac{n}{2}$. Now you have system of two equations which is easy to solve.